# Can't change the twitter button width

Tags: css, twitter

http://boutique40.com/

I want to align the 2 social icons exactly in the center. And actually to do that I want to set to the twitter icon the width value of `80px`, but I can't do it. I only manage to do that in the browser editor; I can't seem to select the right class and `element.style` overides it whatever I do. What is this?

```
element.style {
   width: 110px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

I don't wont to wrap the whole button to change the size (or should I?). The code that should be working is this:

```
 .twitter-share-button { vertical-align:top;
 margin-left:10px; width: 80px;}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Chrome's developer tools `element.style` shows any inline styles that are applied to the selected element.

To override them use `!important`

So to set the button width to 80px you could use:

```
.twitter-share-button {
width: 80px !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle cases where the counter grows beyond the established limits. Twitter has yet to introduce a "fix" that will allow dynamic widths on the counter element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a local style on the button itself, by using the style attribute:

```
style = "width: 80px;"
```

the local style should overwrite it.